# How to figure out interest received from 'cash and cash equivalents' in a balance sheet?

Tags: interest, government-bonds, shares, balance-sheet

Looking at [APPL](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=1)'s [balance sheet](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL&annual), I can see that they have a few million as `cash and cash equivalents`.

I want to know more about `cash and cash equivalents`.  I understand that `cash and cash equivalents` can include raw cash in a bank account, short-term bonds etc etc.  How do I go about finding out how much interest [APPL](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=1) is earning from the `cash and cash equivalents` via raw cash in a bank account, short-term bonds etc etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to (Annual Report)  -> Income Statements -> Interest Income. It wouldn't be in detail in the income statement, but it will point you to the **Notes** section where it will be jotted down in detail.

Comment: Just tried that, i.e. [Annual report](http://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/DisplayFiling.aspx?dcn=0001193125-12-444068) > [Income Statement](http://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/displayfilinginfo.aspx?FilingID=8888271-186135-190338&type=sect&dcn=0001193125-12-444068) and I can't see anything to do with Interest Income?

Comment: @oshirowanen DumbCoder said you won't find it in the detail in the income statement but to look at the **Notes**.  See bottom half of page 36 here:  http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/AAPL/2410976937x0xS1193125-12-444068/320193/filing.pdf .. when in doubt, read the actual annual report (the full version typically available in PDF format) that you can usually find linked to somewhere from the company's own investor relations web site.